# How to use alert dialog with date picker?

Tags: java, android

I want to raise an alert dialog when `to-date` is less than
`from-date`. In the following code I get an exception stating `'Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application'` in the `logcat` for line `alert.show()`.

```
int res = to_date.compareTo(datefrom.from_date);
//res = 0 if date1 is equal to this date2; res < 0 if date1 is before date2; res > 0 of date1 is after date2
if( res<0)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( getApplication() );
    builder.setMessage("To date is lesser than from date")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog,id)->{});
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.getWindow().getAttributes();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your  `getApplication()` context.

You need to pass your `Activity` class context to there. Like, if you'r using code in `Activity` then this should be

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```

OR

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

However if you'r using a code in `Fragment` then it should be

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use activity context here, not application context `new AlertDialog.Builder( getApplication());`

Answer (score 0):

If the application is not moving to another activity when you inflate the `AlertDialog`, pass the context of the calling activity to `AlertDialog.Builder`. Use `YourActivity.this` instead of `getApplication()`.

Here is the [AlertDialog.Builder Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Comment: if I use 'this' in place of 'getApplication' I get error stating that it cannot be supplied to datepicker dialog.

Comment: are you calling this inside a Fragment or Activity?

Comment: If you are creating the alertdialog in an anonymous or inner class, pass YourActivity.this to AlertDialog.builder so it knows that it is created on the Activity context and not the anonymous or inner class

Comment: I am calling in Activity.